# django API, "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

my models

```
class City(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_name


class Place(models.Model):
    place_city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    place_name = models.TextField(max_length=40)
    place_available_slots = models.IntegerField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.place_city, self.place_name)
```

my serializers

```
class PlaceUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Place
        fields = '__all__'
```

my views:

```
class PlaceUpdateAPI(APIView):

    def put(self, request):
        place = Place.objects.get(place_name=request.data.get("place_name"))
        serializer = PlaceUpdateSerializer(place, request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

and error is :

```
{
    "place_city": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."
    ]
}
```

I tried to put data but here is the error. The place_city is a foreign key can someone guide me how to put data through API in Foreign Key.

Comment: You're trying to pass the name of the city (str), but `place_city` is a foreign key (int). If the `Place` is changing city you generally don't want to modify `City` itself, rather assign a different one, you'd do that by passing the id of a `City` to make this work. As far as I'm aware you can't update the OneToOne related model this way, but should e.g. `place.place_city.name=new_name` and then `place.place_city.save()`. How `new_name` can be determined is something that will depend on API usage, it could be a different endpoint.

Comment: @EdoardoFacchinelli this seems like an answer, consider posting it as an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass the name of the city (str), but `place_city` is a foreign key (int).
If the `Place` is changing city you generally don't want to modify `City` itself, rather assign a different one, you'd do that by passing another existing `City.id` to make this work.

If you really need to update the `City` data, as far as I'm aware you can't update a OneToOne related model this way, but should e.g.

```
place.place_city.name=new_name
place.place_city.save()
```

How `new_name` can be determined is something that will depend on API usage, it could be a different endpoint.